# DISTINCT does not remove all duplicates in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates, distinct

I am working with the following query in order to query and adapt purchase data of my customers:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT (order_number),
email,
first_name,
last_name,
purchase_date,
order_price,
source_id,
row_number() over(partition by email order by purchase_date) order_count,
date_diff(
date(purchase_date),
coalesce(date(lag(purchase_date) over(partition by email order by purchase_date)), date(purchase_date)),
day
) purchase_latency 
FROM
(select distinct (order_number), 
email, 
first_name, 
last_name,
purchase_date, 
order_price,
source_id
FROM my_dataset_orders where source_id != "test_order" AND order_price != 0)
```

As you can see, I want to avoid having duplicates of the value "order_number" in my dataset. Thus, I have tried to remove duplicates in two ways, as you can see in the query: First, one time with the first ***DISTINCT*** that I use immediately in row 2 and second, the other time within the **FROM** section where I already try to select distinct values.

However, when I download the final dataset as CSV, I still have some remaining order_number duplicates in the data. Does anyone know how to avoid this or where my mistake is?

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the column after the `distinct`?  Do you think they actually do anything?

Comment: Hey! Yes, indeed! I thought this is how I can select to take distinct values of „order_number“ without considering the other values as distinct ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one arbitrary row for each order, then one method is:

```
select array_agg(o limit 1)[ordinal(0)].*
from my_dataset_orders o
where source_id <> 'test_order' and order_price <> 0
group by o.order_number
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you! I don’t completely get the code and how I can combine it with my existing query.

Comment: I also thought that a workaround could be to only select order_number, then apply DISTINCT and then left join my query as seen above. But I would also not know how to correctly apply this method.

Comment: @sql-newby- . . . This would be the subquery.